# modify sequence so it converges to pi

Tags: real-analysis, numerical-methods

Modify sequence  by Archimedes

$s_{n+1}=\frac{2^{n+1}}{ \sqrt{2} } \sqrt{ 1 -\sqrt{1-(s_n/2^{n})^2}}; s_2=2\sqrt{2} $

so that it approaches $\pi$

---

the issue is that it is going to $0$

$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \sqrt{1-(s_n/2^n)^2}=1 $$

making $s_{n+1}$ go to $0$

Now

$$ \begin{aligned}
&\sqrt{1-\sqrt{1-(s_n/2^n)^2}} * \sqrt{1-\sqrt{1-(s_n/2^n)^2}} 
\\&=\sqrt{(1-\sqrt{1-(s_n/2^n)^2}) * (1-\sqrt{1-(s_n/2^n)^2)}}
\\&=\sqrt{1 +\sqrt{1-(s_n/2^n)^2} - \sqrt{1-(s_n/2^n)^2}+1 - (\frac{s_n}{2^n})^2}
\\&=\sqrt{2-(\frac{s_n}{2^n})^2}
\end{aligned}$$

multiplying it  $s_{n+1}$ by $\frac{ \sqrt{1+(s_n/2^n)^2} }{\sqrt{1+(s_n/2^n)^2}}  $

$$s_{n+1}=\frac{2^{n+1}}{ \sqrt{2} } \sqrt{ 1 -\sqrt{1-(s_n/2^{n})^2}}*  \frac{ \sqrt{1+(s_n/2^n)^2} }{\sqrt{1+(s_n/2^n)^2}}$$
is
$$S_{n+1} = \frac{\frac{2^{n+1}}{\sqrt{2}} * \sqrt{2-(\frac{s_n}{2^n})^2}}{\sqrt{1+\sqrt{1-(\frac{s_n}{2^n})^2}}}$$

need to see if that goes to $\pi$ better. need to throw it to a for loop and see that it dosent go to zero

*Appreciate feedback*

Comment: Your two layer radical is multiplied by something that goes to infinity.  You cannot guarantee the whole limit goes to zero.

Comment: It's the sequence of perimeters of a square, then a regular octagon, then a regular 16-gon, generally a regular $2^n$-gon inscribed in a circle of unit diameter.  It will go to $\pi$.

Answer (score 1):

In the end what you should get is $$s_n=2^n\sin\frac\pi{2^n}$$ so that indeed 
$$
\lim s_n=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin(\pi x)}{x}=\frac{d\sin(\pi x)}{dx}\Big|_{x=0}=\pi\cos(0)=\pi.
$$

As said in the comments, the formula arises by inscribing first a square into the circle and then refine it by halving the angles in the regular polygon. $s_n$ is half the perimeter of the $2^n$-gon.

---

Let's see how the formula emerges.  For $n=2$ we have $s_2/4=(\sqrt{2})/2=\sin(\pi/4)$.  Then if one sets $s_n/2^n=\sin\theta_n$, then the given formula leads to
$$
(1/\sqrt{2})\sqrt{1-\sqrt{1-\sin^2θ_n}}=\sqrt{(1-\cosθ_n)/2}=\sqrt{\sin^2(θ_n/2)}=\sin(θ_n/2)
$$
which matches the required formula for $(s_{n+1})/(2^{n+1})$.

Comment: Can you show how your,formula gives the proper value for $s_{n+1}$?  I tried to add that logic but pressed a bad button and gave up.  Thx!

Comment: Indeed that does not work, as the task says, one has to modify the iteration formula to get convergence (and to a non-zero number, which then is $\pi$).

Comment: Oh yes we (and Archimedes) did! See the edit.

Comment: You are right. There was some selective memory on my side that did not remember the denominator $\sqrt2$ of the factor in front while writing the answer. Also, this wrong idea seemed right since that is an easy part to put wrong in the formula in the task for the students to correct. Now it is unclear what the "modify" refers to as the original formula is correct.

Comment: OP looked at the square roots and thought the limit was zero.  But the power of 2 in the multiplier prevents that.

Comment: Archimedes began with an equilateral triangle and calculated the approximate perimeter of a regular $96$-gon, deducing that $3\frac {10}{71}<\pi<3\frac {1}{7},$  although we can be sure that he was capable of being more precise,